# Can't find mx.rpc.xml.XMLEncoder/Decoder

Tags: flex3, flexbuilder

I'm using the Flex 3.5 compiler (on Flash Builder 4), and I need to use these classes, and I just can't find them! I looked at the source code, and they are in the 3.4 branch, so I guess they must also be in 3.5. What am I missing? What's the swc file that contains them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The XMLDecoder class has "[ExcludeClass]" in the definition. Flash Builder then do not provide the class in IntelliSense PopUp. Just add an import "import mx.rpc.xml.XMLDecoder;" to the head of your class and use it. This should solve your problem.